# I can't seem to get Java to read my text document

Tags: java, text

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Average
{
    public void Average()
    {
        Scanner in = (new Scanner("J:\\AP Comptuter Science\\Semester 2\\Exeptions\\13.1\\numbers.txt"));
        try{
            String test = in.nextLine();
        } catch(NullPointerException i) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
        }

        int total = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        while(in.hasNextInt()){
            total = total + in.nextInt();
            counter++;
        }
        total = total / counter;
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

I have a project for my AP Comp class and i did the work according to the notes, but the file "numbers" isn't being read and i get the answer 0 when it should be some huge number.

Comment: Are you sure about that path? Really sure? `Semester      2`?

Comment: check the spacing in the scanner path, for example Scanner in = (new Scanner("J:\\AP Comptuter Science\\Semester2\\Exeptions\\13.1\\numbers.txt"));

Comment: *"isn't being read"* What does that mean? You get an error? As in.... division by zero, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should correct your path, and probably put it in the same directory as your class files. And instead of providing a path to the scanner you should also give it a file. It should look something like this.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average
   {

        public void printAverage(){
            File file = new File(""J:\\AP Comptuter Science\\Semester 2\\Exeptions\\13.1\\numbers.txt"");
            Scanner scan;

            try {
                scan = new Scanner(file);
                int total = 0, counter = 0;

                while(scan.hasNextInt()){
                    System.out.println("loop");
                    total = total + scan.nextInt();
                    counter++;

                }
                if(counter != 0)
                    total = total/counter;
                System.out.println(total);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

   }
```

Comment: I get the error unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown   The highlighted part is Scanner in  = (new Scanner(file));

Answer (score 1):

```
new Scanner("J:\\AP Comptuter Science\\Semester      2\\Exeptions\\13.1\\numbers.txt")
```

You are calling [`Scanner(String source)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29), which does not read the file; it scans the string itself.

What you need is probably [`public Scanner(File source)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)), as follows:

```
new Scanner(new File("J:\\AP Comptuter Science\\Semester      2\\Exeptions\\13.1\\numbers.txt"))
```

You also need to check the path, there almost certainly aren't 5 spaces between "Semester" and "2"

Overall I would strongly urge you to step through your code in a debugger instead of just running. If you had done that, you would have seen that after executing

```
String test = in.nextLine();
```

The string `test` contains the name of the file rather than its contents.

There are other improvements possible, consider posting in the codereview stackexchange after you are able to make it work

Comment: the five spaces are from me formatting the file so i could post the code.

Comment: But more importantly you are using the wrong method

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, the code has several issues:

a) `new Scanner(String)` reads the string instead of the file

b) path seems to be incorrect

c) handling of `DivideByZero` and `FileNotFound` exceptions

Please see the following code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class Average{
    public void average(){
        Scanner in = null;
        try{
            in = (new Scanner(new File("J:\\AP Comptuter Science\\Semester 2\\Exeptions\\13.1\\numbers.txt")));
            String test = in.nextLine();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException | FileNotFoundException i){
            System.out.println("Error: " + i.getMessage());
        }
        int total = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while(in != null && in.hasNextInt())
        {
            total = total + in.nextInt();
            counter++;
        }
        Float average = null;
        if (counter > 0) { //to avoid divide by zero error
            average = (float)total / counter;
            System.out.println("Average: "+average);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Average().average();
    }
}
```

This works for only numbers.txt which has integers separated by space as required by the `nextInt()` method of `Scanner` class.

Comment: Thank you so much i realize that my input is wrong and why it didn't work now that i compared the two.